# "Keep with next" paragraph option when there's a section break

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have a document where headings are centred in the page, followed by text in two columns, followed by next heading not in a column, and again more text in two columns, and so on.

The change from one column to two columns prompts word to insert a section break (continuous).

The problem is that one of the headings is placed just before the end of the page and gets cut off from its text. Using the "Keep with next" paragraph option doesn't work, presumably because of the section break. The document happens to be in right-to-left but I don't think that's the problem.

How do I make this work. Can you change columns from 1 to 2 without a section break? Or can you get "Keep with next" to work despite a section break?

Word 2016

Thank you

Comment: OK no answers (yet?). I think the problem here is a basic design flaw in word. If you're going to use section breaks for formatting changes like columns, then you can't treat it as a normal section break as though it was something completely new. So you should still be able to use options like "Keep with next".

Comment: follow on - They need to make a separate type of break, called say a formatting break, and allow options like "Keep with next" (and any other formatting options like this which will have the same problem - admittedly haven't thought of any yet) to cross over such breaks.